# Safari Share Sheet accessible to UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari

I want to add a **Share** bar button item to my top Navigation Bar that works like the one in Safari (**send a link via SMS Message, copy a link, etc**), are developers allowed access to that, or is it something where I have to create my own?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out you can do this with `UIActivityViewController`!

Let me know if you have any questions on this-